# How to set group of a new user?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

This might seem an easy question, but I can't figure out the answer.

I have a user table and groups table in a database that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see they are both connected with each other. The groups table contains the following entries:

1. Administrator
2. Support
3. Purchasing
4. Selling

Now I want to add a new user with the following code using Entity Framework:

```
private void AddUser()
{
    using (var context = new AzubiTestEntities())
    {
        var user = new Benutzer();

        user.Name = Username;
        user.Passwort = GenerateHashPassword();

        user.Gruppen = ???

        user.Anlegedatum = DateTime.Now;
        user.Loeschdatum = null;
        user.ErstellerID = 1;

        context.Benutzer.Add(user);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How can I set the group of this user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you miss a direct one-on-many foreign key like gruppenID in the Benutzer table, I assume you're using a many-to-many middle table.

In this case (where you don't see the middle foreign key) you have to get the group from the database and assign it to the user.Gruppen property.

```
private void AddUser()
{
    using (var context = new AzubiTestEntities())
    {
        var user = new Benutzer();
        var gruppen = context.Gruppen.First(x => x.GruppenID == [group id]);

        user.Name = Username;
        user.Passwort = GenerateHashPassword();

        user.Gruppen = gruppen;

        user.Anlegedatum = DateTime.Now;
        user.Loeschdatum = null;
        user.ErstellerID = 1;

        context.Benutzer.Add(user);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx